# robot_localization ekf_node fuse 2hz depth measurement

Tags: ros, navigation, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am using robot_localization ekf to fuse 100 hz imu, 4hz twist(x,y,z velocity) and 2hz pose(only z position). The pose is only has z, which is the position measured from pressure sensor then convert to odom frame. What I am really want to do is using this z as the final result in the filtered odometry, like trust this measurement the most.

The param file is here: [check](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o7uvqS-VqrQUH9VXBLCNCpa1FaUkOcGD/view?usp=sharing). The depth is just keeping draft, the pose seems not helped in the ekf. Any suggestions? Thanks for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379619/robot_localization-ekf_node-fuse-2hz-depth-measurement/) by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 214 on 2021-06-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I adjust the configure, not it looks good.

```
frequency: 50
#sensor_timeout: 1.0
two_d_mode: false
transform_time_offset: 0.0
transform_timeout: 0.0
print_diagnostics: true
debug: false
# debug_out_file: /path/to/debug/file.txt
publish_tf: true

# publish_acceleration: false
smooth_lagged_data: true
history_length: 1.0

map_frame: map              # Defaults to "map" if unspecified
odom_frame: odom            # Defaults to "odom" if unspecified
base_link_frame: base_link  # Defaults to "base_link" if unspecified
world_frame: odom           # Defaults to the value of odom_frame if unspecified

# [X,      Y,       Z,
#  roll,   pitch,   yaw,
#  V_x,    V_y,     V_z,
#  V_roll, V_pitch, V_yaw,
#  ax,     ay,      az]

imu0: /rov/processed/ahrs/imu_madgwick
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              true, true, true,
              false, false, false,
              true, true, true,
              true, true, true]
imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true      # the raw data is not removed
imu0_nodelay: true
imu0_differential: false
imu0_relative: false
imu0_queue_size: 100
imu0_pose_rejection_threshold: 0.8                 # Note the difference in parameter names
imu0_twist_rejection_threshold: 0.8                #
imu0_linear_acceleration_rejection_threshold: 0.8  #

twist0: /rov/processed/dvl/twist_filtered
twist0_config: [false, false, false,
                false, false, false,
                true, true, true,
                false, false, false,
                false, false, false]
twist0_nodelay: true
twist0_differential: false
twist0_relative: false
twist0_queue_size: 20

pose0: /rov/processed/dvl/depth
pose0_config: [false, false, true,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false]
pose0_differential: false
pose0_relative: false
pose0_queue_size: 10
pose0_rejection_threshold: 2  # Note the difference in parameter name
pose0_nodelay: true

# [ADVANCED] The process noise covariance matrix can be difficult to tune, and can vary for each application, so it is
# exposed as a configuration parameter. This matrix represents the noise we add to the total error after each
# prediction step. The better the omnidirectional motion model matches your system, the smaller these values can be.
# However, if users find that a given variable is slow to converge, one approach is to increase the
# process_noise_covariance diagonal value for the variable in question, which will cause the filter's predicted error
# to be larger, which will cause the filter to trust the incoming measurement more during correction. The values are
# ordered as x, y, z, roll, pitch, yaw, vx, vy, vz, vroll, vpitch, vyaw, ax, ay, az. Defaults to the matrix below if
# unspecified.

### set larger value for trusted sensor measurements
process_noise_covariance: [1e-8, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    1e-8, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01,  0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.5,   0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0.5,   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0.5, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3,  0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3]

# [ADVANCED] This represents the initial value for the state estimate error covariance matrix. Setting a diagonal
# value (variance) to a large value will result in rapid convergence for initial measurements of the variable in
# question. Users should take care not to use large values for variables that will not be measured directly. The values
# are ordered as x, y, z, roll, pitch, yaw, vx, vy, vz, vroll, vpitch, vyaw, ax, ay, az. Defaults to the matrix below
#if unspecified.
initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-6, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    1e-6, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-6, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,   0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     1.0,   0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     1.0,   0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     1.0,  0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    1.0,  0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    1.0]
```

---

Originally posted by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) with karma: 214 on 2021-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0